# R levelplot and interpolation

Tags: r, lattice, levelplot

some days ago I managed to make levelplots, with interpolation, with the following command within a script:

```
levelplot(jan~lon*lat,APM,main="Jan",panel=panel.levelplot.raster,interpolate=T)
```

I accidentaly did not keep that session, only the script, so it is not possible for me to go through the history and recover all the commands I had used.

Now, after loading latticeExtra, the same command produces an empty plot. On the other hand, leaving out the last two elements of the instruction, i.e.:

```
levelplot(jan~lon*lat,APM,main="Jan")
```

The graph is drawn.

I'd like to have interpolation at the surface, but something is going wrong with

```
panel=panel.levelplot.raster
```

the same behaviour happens when rasterVis is loaded.
I guess I am missing something... any help?

The data has the following structure:

```
> head(APM)
    lat  lon  jan  feb  mar  apr  may  jun   jul   aug  sep  oct  nov  dec
1 -18.5 10.5 29.7 28.8 25.6 25.6 26.8 29.9  35.5  46.8 35.5 27.5 27.5 27.9
2 -17.5 10.5 28.8 29.8 26.3 26.2 27.8 31.6  39.7  63.1 40.4 27.6 27.6 28.3
3 -16.5 10.5 28.7 30.0 26.9 26.8 28.6 32.1  41.1 109.4 42.8 29.7 28.9 29.4
4 -15.5 10.5 28.4 29.5 27.5 26.9 29.1 34.2  46.4 109.5 40.8 29.7 29.7 28.5
5 -14.5 10.5 28.2 29.3 27.4 27.8 27.8 42.8  60.7 104.3 49.1 29.4 28.8 28.6
6 -13.5 10.5 27.8 28.4 27.7 28.3 29.8 41.2 102.8 105.7 47.8 29.5 28.5 28.0
```

totalling 224 cells listed by latitude and longitude:

```
> dput(APM)
structure(list(lat = c(-18.5, -17.5, -16.5, -15.5, -14.5, -13.5, 
-12.5, -11.5, -10.5, -9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, -5.5, -18.5, -17.5, 
-16.5, -15.5, -14.5, -13.5, -12.5, -11.5, -10.5, -9.5, -8.5, 
-7.5, -6.5, -5.5, -18.5, -17.5, -16.5, -15.5, -14.5, -13.5, -12.5, 
-11.5, -10.5, -9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, -5.5, -18.5, -17.5, -16.5, 
-15.5, -14.5, -13.5, -12.5, -11.5, -10.5, -9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, 
-5.5, -18.5, -17.5, -16.5, -15.5, -14.5, -13.5, -12.5, -11.5, 
-10.5, -9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, -5.5, -18.5, -17.5, -16.5, -15.5, 
-14.5, -13.5, -12.5, -11.5, -10.5, -9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, -5.5, 
-18.5, -17.5, -16.5, -15.5, -14.5, -13.5, -12.5, -11.5, -10.5, 
-9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, -5.5, -18.5, -17.5, -16.5, -15.5, -14.5, 
-13.5, -12.5, -11.5, -10.5, -9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, -5.5, -18.5, 
-17.5, -16.5, -15.5, -14.5, -13.5, -12.5, -11.5, -10.5, -9.5, 
-8.5, -7.5, -6.5, -5.5, -18.5, -17.5, -16.5, -15.5, -14.5, -13.5, 
-12.5, -11.5, -10.5, -9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, -5.5, -18.5, -17.5, 
-16.5, -15.5, -14.5, -13.5, -12.5, -11.5, -10.5, -9.5, -8.5, 
-7.5, -6.5, -5.5, -18.5, -17.5, -16.5, -15.5, -14.5, -13.5, -12.5, 
-11.5, -10.5, -9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, -5.5, -18.5, -17.5, -16.5, 
-15.5, -14.5, -13.5, -12.5, -11.5, -10.5, -9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, 
-5.5, -18.5, -17.5, -16.5, -15.5, -14.5, -13.5, -12.5, -11.5, 
-10.5, -9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, -5.5, -18.5, -17.5, -16.5, -15.5, 
-14.5, -13.5, -12.5, -11.5, -10.5, -9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, -5.5, 
-18.5, -17.5, -16.5, -15.5, -14.5, -13.5, -12.5, -11.5, -10.5, 
-9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, -5.5), lon = c(10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 
10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 11.5, 
11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 
11.5, 11.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 
12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 
13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 
14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 
15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 
15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 
16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 
17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 18.5, 18.5, 
18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 
18.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 
19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 
20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 
21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 22.5, 
22.5, 22.5, 22.5, 22.5, 22.5, 22.5, 22.5, 22.5, 22.5, 22.5, 22.5, 
22.5, 22.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 
23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 
24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 
25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5
), jan = c(29.7, 28.8, 28.7, 28.4, 28.2, 27.8, 28, 29.4, 30.3, 
32.5, 33.2, 33.5, 33.1, 34.3, 28.4, 29.4, 29.6, 29, 28.9, 28.8, 
28.5, 28.9, 29.9, 31, 32.2, 32.9, 35.8, 37.4, 30, 27.4, 29.6, 
30, 28.4, 30.6, 30.4, 29.9, 30.2, 31.3, 33.9, 35.5, 35.8, 34.5, 
30.3, 23.8, 25.2, 23.2, 22.9, 24, 27.2, 29.3, 31.6, 32.3, 31, 
31.4, 37.3, 37.4, 24.9, 25.1, 23.4, 21.2, 23.5, 22.8, 23.5, 24.5, 
26, 27.7, 28.6, 33.3, 37.3, 40.7, 37.9, 38.5, 27.1, 22.5, 24.7, 
23.3, 24.7, 24.8, 26.6, 27.4, 30.7, 33.9, 35.9, 37.6, 30.7, 29.5, 
26.6, 24.1, 24.1, 25.4, 25.4, 25.7, 28, 28.2, 32.9, 36.3, 35.2, 
40.4, 22.7, 25.5, 26.5, 24.6, 24.3, 24, 25.8, 26.7, 29.4, 31.8, 
35.4, 38, 37.4, 41.3, 22.2, 23.7, 26.8, 25.8, 25.3, 24, 25.1, 
26.9, 29.6, 31.8, 34.4, 35.6, 39.3, 40.1, 26.2, 26.2, 26, 25.8, 
25.3, 23.2, 24.5, 25.9, 26.9, 30.8, 33.3, 38.3, 40.2, 41.2, 26.9, 
26.4, 27.1, 23.1, 22.9, 24, 28.5, 26.9, 27.1, 31, 32.7, 36.6, 
38, 41.6, 26.6, 27.2, 27.3, 26, 23.6, 25.8, 33.2, 33.8, 25.8, 
28.1, 31.6, 34.7, 35.3, 38.5, 27.3, 28.1, 28.6, 27, 31.5, 31.8, 
29.9, 27.6, 25.4, 28.4, 29.8, 32.2, 36.4, 36.8, 28.2, 26.2, 27.3, 
27, 27.1, 23.7, 23.5, 25.3, 26.1, 29, 29.3, 29.3, 36.4, 35.1, 
24.2, 25.1, 23.5, 23.1, 24, 24.2, 24.3, 26.7, 26.7, 26.8, 29.3, 
30.4, 33.3, 33.4, 24.8, 24.3, 24.5, 24.8, 26.1, 24.6, 25, 25.3, 
27.2, 26.8, 28.9, 30.5, 31.2, 33.1), feb = c(28.8, 29.8, 30, 
29.5, 29.3, 28.4, 28.6, 28.7, 28.7, 28.5, 29.4, 32.2, 34.4, 37.4, 
29.4, 30.5, 30.8, 30.7, 29.6, 28.3, 28, 28.4, 28.4, 29, 29.5, 
31.4, 33.3, 37.1, 31.7, 26.5, 29.8, 30.4, 28.4, 28.9, 27.7, 27.8, 
29.3, 30, 30.4, 31.7, 32.9, 34.7, 29.1, 23.5, 24.2, 23.3, 22.7, 
23.6, 25.4, 26.4, 27.7, 28.1, 26.9, 27.5, 30.4, 31.6, 22.3, 24.7, 
23.7, 21.2, 23.4, 22.5, 22.3, 21.7, 23.2, 23.3, 23.2, 27.5, 31.6, 
34, 33, 33.3, 26.3, 22.5, 23.9, 24, 24.5, 23.7, 24.2, 24.5, 25.4, 
27.8, 31, 33.4, 29.3, 27.5, 24.7, 23.2, 23.5, 24.7, 25.7, 25.4, 
25.8, 25.6, 27.2, 30.7, 30.4, 35, 21.4, 23.3, 24.1, 24.7, 25.2, 
25.2, 25.6, 25.9, 27.7, 26.9, 30.1, 31.5, 32, 34.5, 20.2, 22.4, 
24.9, 25.1, 25.3, 25.5, 24.1, 25.8, 26.2, 28.4, 29.3, 30.9, 33.5, 
35.6, 24.3, 24.2, 24, 24.5, 24.9, 24.7, 23.8, 25, 26.2, 27.1, 
29.9, 31.3, 34.6, 34.7, 25.3, 23.6, 24.9, 22.6, 23.1, 23.1, 25.3, 
26.8, 24.9, 25.1, 28.1, 30.7, 32.1, 34.2, 24, 23.4, 24.6, 25.6, 
24.9, 26.4, 30.6, 31.2, 22.2, 23.9, 27.6, 30.8, 29.1, 29.7, 24, 
23.6, 25.4, 25.8, 29.9, 29.5, 27.2, 26.3, 23.5, 24.5, 25.6, 27, 
28.9, 28.3, 24.4, 22, 23.4, 24.9, 25.4, 22.7, 23, 23, 22.4, 23.7, 
24.6, 24.9, 29.8, 28.5, 21.3, 22.8, 21.3, 21.1, 21.7, 22.8, 24.4, 
23.2, 23.3, 22.4, 25.4, 26.3, 27.3, 27.1, 22.8, 22.1, 21.4, 21.9, 
24.1, 24.1, 26, 23.5, 23.8, 22.5, 23, 24.9, 26.5, 28)), .Names = c("lat", 
"lon", "jan", "feb"), row.names = c(NA, 
-224L))
```

Comment: A reproducible example of the irreproducible plot might help!

Comment: hello thanks for the interest. just updated the question with an example on how the data is actually structured. Hope that helps.

Comment: In the snippet of your data, there is no variation in `lon`. This makes the irreproducibility reproducible (warnings are produced and there is nothing in the plotting window) and may be the cause of your problems. If there is variation in `lon` in your full dataset, please consider replacing the results of `head(APM)` with the results of `dput(APM)`.

Comment: The plot works with the first 152 entries of `lat`, `lon` and `jan` that can be garnered from what you posted (`dput` was cut off...). AGAIN, please post a reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: thanks again for your interest. I do not think there is an issue with the data itself, as plotting a levelplot of jan versus lat and lon without interpolating goes fine.

Answer (score 2):

The following produces a plot in a fresh interactive session of R

```
APM <- results of dput(APM) from the OP

library(latticeExtra)

levelplot(jan~lon*lat,APM,main="Jan",panel=panel.levelplot.raster,interpolate=T)
```

or alternatively

```
levelplot(jan~lon*lat,APM,main="Jan",interpolate=TRUE, useRaster = TRUE)
```

[image: interpolation works!!]

If this is not working for you, check to see if you have the latest versions of the packages in question; for example,

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
latticeExtra_0.6-24
lattice_0.20-10
RColorBrewer_1.0-5
```

If the problem still is not resolved, there's something else that hasn't been mentioned in this post.

Comment: simply solved by updating the packages. Thanks very much for your time.